# ClassNotFoundException Netbeans Maven Library wrapper

Tags: maven, wrapper, netbeans-platform

I was able to follow the tutorial [here](http://netbeans.dzone.com/how-to-nb-djnative-swing) and convert it to a Maven application.

I got the loading part right, but when I try to use it, it can't find the appropriate swt classes (When ran from windows 64). I did it on a Maven project. Here's the relevant part of the respective pom for the Windows 64 module:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- To have the jar plugin pickup the nbm generated manifest -->
                    <useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
                    <moduleType>normal</moduleType>
                    swt.windows.64/1</codeNameBase>
                    <publicPackages>
                        <publicPackage>org.eclipse.swt</publicPackage>
                    </publicPackages>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I translates to org.eclipse.swt.*. It seems to be a Maven module issue since it already tries to load from correct module.

```
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWT starting from ModuleCL@25e0dee5[djproject.core] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@6783113b[swt.windows.64]] and declared parents [ModuleCL@32821bf7[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common]]

Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWT
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.initialize_(SWTNativeInterface.java:213)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.initialize(NativeInterface.java:71)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.open_(SWTNativeInterface.java:337)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.open(NativeInterface.java:100)
    at synamicd.windows64.support.Windows64BrowserProvider.initialize(Windows64BrowserProvider.java:25)
```

Any help is more than welcomed!

**Edit:**
Code is available [here](https://javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/multi-os-swt-netbeans-support).

Answer (score 1):

when I try to build the application at the bitbucket location, it's build order suggests that none of the swt modules are used in the app - http://screencast.com/t/LMxIPy6A6ZUL

Comment: and when I just try building the mac64 project with dependencies, I get this error. http://screencast.com/t/BZTNT4gnSB

Comment: You where completely right! I just addressed those issues and added a demo module showing the behavior. About the missing dependencies those should be installed locally. They are in the libs folder for now.

Comment: Those where errors when I transplanted the code to a public repo since it worked on original repo.

Comment: it still doesn't build out of the box. Please move your local repository away, disable your mirrors and try building. dj:DJNAtiveSwing:1.0 is still missing, not in the lib folder (I've installed the other two dependencies). Coincidently there's a module named similarly in your codebase which however has no dependencies to JDNAativeSwing..

Comment: I'll take a look so it compiles out of the box

Comment: Pushed changes to repo to make it build from scratch after seeing the behavior you describe after wiping out my repo. Also it now installs local libs as part of the build, but requires Maven 3.0.4.